# Azure Logic App - Issue with double quotes in Liquid Map

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps, dotliquid

I am trying to convert a JSON from one schema to another and I am having issue in transforming string fields which have double quotes in the value. Below mentioned is the input JSON:

```
{
  "inputvalue": "Test \" word"
}
```

The liquid map which I am using is:

```
{   
    "outputvalue": "{{content.inputvalue}}"
}
```

The transform is giving an error while running the logic app -

> "An error occurred while converting the transformed value to JSON. The
>   transformed value is not a valid JSON."

I tried using `Escape` filter but that actually converts the double quotes to encoded string which I will be forced to convert it back. Also, it not only converts double quotes, but also converts all special characters like comma, single quotes etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `'` instead of `"` in your liquid template.

```
{   
    "outputvalue": '{{content.inputvalue}}'
}
```

After running the logic app, we will get the result as below:
[image]

If you don't want the `\` before the `"`, you can replace it with space in the result string.

**Update:**

If the input text contains `'`, you can try to use the liquid map below:

```
{% assign input = content.inputvalue | Replace: '"', '\"' %}
{   
    "test": "{{input}}"
}
```

Because the `\"` in your input text will be transformed to `"` in liquid, so we need to use Replace filter to replace it to `\"` again.

Then we can get the result:
[image]

Comment: This will not work if my input text contains both single and double quotes

Comment: Hi @SillyJohn I have updated my solution, please have a check.

Comment: Make sure to take that a step further and escape \ with \.  | Replace: '\\', '\\'  | Replace: '"', '\"'